# Updating a variable in naming a file in SAS

Tags: excel, sas

I'm somewhat new to SAS. I'm trying to update a file name to write an excel file through a loop, but am having trouble assigning the file name. Here's my code:

```
%MACRO loop;
    %DO year1 = 1995 %TO 2008;
        DATA _NULL_;
            dailyret = catx(STRIP(&year1),
            '''/h1/usr11/angeli/finland/haz/phreg_dailyret_',  '.csv''');

           *to save output to excel;
           ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP
           file= %QUOTE(dailyret)
           STYLE=minimal
           OPTIONS ( Orientation = 'landscape'
           FitToPage = 'yes'
           Pages_FitWidth = '1'
           Pages_FitHeight = '100' );

           *a block of code that runs the program, irrelevant to my question;

           ods tagsets.excelxp close;

       RUN;
    %END;
%MEND loop;

%loop;
```

I have tried many variations of this, but every time, I always get an error message along the lines of "ERROR: No logical assign for filename DAILYRET".

Is there any way I can do this so that I don't have to put physical quotes in the line with "file=" and be able to update the year?

Thank you so much!

-Angel

Comment: What is the purpose of the DATA step? Also you seem to have a lot of global statements (ODS, OPTIONS) mixed into the middle of your data step.

Comment: The purpose of the DATA step was to assign the concatenated string to the variable "dailyret" so I could assign the variable "dailyret" to the file name. I have tried directly assigning "catx(STRIP(&year1), '''/h1/usr11/angeli/finland/haz/phreg_dailyret_',  '.csv''')" to the file name, but it gave me an error as well. Honestly, since I'm pretty new to SAS, I'm not sure exactly what ODS and OPTIONS do, but when I searched up how to create a file to excel, that is the code I found. Is there any way I can update the MACRO variable year1 and have it assigned to the file name?

Comment: For this simple problem just place the macro variable reference where you want.  For a more complicated problem you might run a data _null_ step that generates a macro variable (using CALL SYMPUTX() function) that you could then use after the data step ends to generate other code, like an ODS statement.

Comment: What version of SAS do you have? I noticed a CSV extension, what type of excel file do you want to create, a data file or a file with tables and reports and multiple sheets? If just a CSV file, consider proc export.

Comment: @Tom I'm not quite understanding what you mean when you say to place the macro variable reference where I want.

Comment: @Reeza I have version 9.2 for SAS. I'm trying to create a CSV excel file. Would PROC EXPORT do the job too?

Comment: @Angel Li - There is normally not any need to use cat() functions when using macro variables. If you have a macro variable YEAR with 2013 as its content and you want to generate the string `final2013data` then you just replace the characters 2013 with the macro variable reference. `final&year.data` See my answer for example of how to use a macro variable's value to reference a filename.

Comment: @Tom Would I be able to create an excel file using that format?

Comment: @Reeza I just read up on PROC EXPORT and it seems that it needs a data set to export to an external file. However, I am running a proportional hazard model inside the code, which generates many tables. And it seems that the definition of OUTFILE must be in quotes, but maybe there is a way around it?

Comment: Nope, proc export does require a data set. You cant create a CSV file from that type of output.

Comment: @Reeza Is there a way to do what I want to do then? Or would I have to do it manually or use a different programming language?

Comment: @Tom answer is correct. The xml file can be opened in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

To reference a macro variable prefix it with an `&`.  Make sure to use double quote characters `"` to quote the filename since macro triggers are not resolved inside of single quotes.

You can also optionally append a period to the macro name so that the parser knows where the macro variable name ends and regular text starts again.  This means that when you want to append an extension that starts with a period you need to have two periods since the first will be used to mark the end of the macro variable reference.

```
%MACRO loop;
  %DO year1 = 1995 %TO 2008;
    ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP
        file= "/h1/usr11/angeli/finland/haz/phreg_dailyret_&year1..xml"
        STYLE=minimal
        OPTIONS ( Orientation = 'landscape'
                  FitToPage = 'yes'
                  Pages_FitWidth = '1'
                  Pages_FitHeight = '100' 
                )
    ;

*-------------------;
*a block of code that runs the program, irrelevant to my question;
*-------------------;

    ods tagsets.excelxp close;

  %END;
%MEND loop;
```

Comment: I tried the code that you wrote and it works! Thank you very much! Sorry I'm new to this site (and SAS) and didn't see your code earlier!